# Selenium opens multiple chromedrivers and wont close them

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, google-chrome-headless

I started using headless chrome for jenkins integration and changed the code in my base file. but now when i run a test I see multiple chromedrivers are started and the driver doesn't close when the last test is finished.

I didn't have this problem before switching to headless mode.

Here is my TestBase class [TestBase.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcdiH.png)

And here is the problem. After all these new chromedrivers the test runs successfully, but a lot of chromedriver accumulates in the background.
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE2aX.png)

I tried to use driver.close and driver.quit functions in the test's @After method but it didn't work like old times too. After using headless mode, I can't close them because as you can see there are multiple chromedrivers in the background.

Comment: I highly doubt that this happened after switching to headless. Its bit hard to say what exactly happens because we dont see before/after test methods. Make sure you are starting and quiting the browser before/after every test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to obtain control over the service itself you need to use `DriverService` object. The example:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions() // Your options here
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService
    .createServiceWithConfig(options);
service.start();

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service);

// Do your test here

driver.quit(); // close session
service.stop(); // stop service
```