# Selenium - Method quit() and close() doesn't work properly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I work on a crawler project where there are 3 machines executing 10 instances each. Exists a method tearDown to close the instances when entire crawler process is finished.

```
    public void tearDown(){
        if(this.driver != null){
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

The problem i'm fencing is that in some cases when the process is finished there are some instances from chromedriver.exe stuck in the task manager. What can I do to ensure the finalization of these instances?

I've tried close instances using taskkill, but in some cases doesn't work.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: From a brief read: It _should_ be sufficient to call `quit` only. Also, are you sure that you haven't scoped another driver there? You refer to `this.driver` the one time, but to `driver` the other. If that's also not fixing your problem, you should be able to to `taskkill /IM chromedriver.exe /F` (assuming you have proper permissions to do so) - the thing I would do is to use the [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface and use my class using the driver with try-with-resources.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, it's help a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium opens multiple chromedrivers and wont close them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516128/selenium-opens-multiple-chromedrivers-and-wont-close-them)

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you want to close the driver session it should be done with `driver.quit();`
No need to perform `driver.close();` on the same `driver` instance before applying `driver.quit();`. This will have no added value.
So your code can be shortened to be

```java
public void tearDown(){
    if(this.driver != null){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Only using `quit` is known not to release the memory back to the OS, while `close` does the job. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591175/how-to-close-python-selenium-webdriver-window) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591175/how-to-close-python-selenium-webdriver-window) for example.

Comment: @sourcream Thank you for the comment. But I did not find in the discussion you refered to any evidence that `driver.quit` not realising the memory. Probably you are talking about cases where browser crashed and the there were no `driver.quit` in the tear down. (Even crashed `driver` need to be closed. It may not realise the memory until you do it explicitly).
AFAIK the only difference between these 2 methods is: `close` closes the currently active tab  - not the entire session. While `quit` closes the entire session, the entire driver.

Comment: Also, you mentined 2 links while they both pointing on the same discussion...

Comment: no, I meant actual memory leaks, without any previous crashes. The first link hints on that, as the OP says he can't close everything using `quit`. But in the second link (which I provided the wrong url as you pointed out, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77343709/17987266) is the correct one) the discussion is clearly about memory leaks. I myself have experienced the same: creating multiple webdrivers fills up the memory very quickly, even when using `quit` between instantiations. The problem goes away if I use `close` instead.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are talking about. I can't confirm or contradict that. Thank you for this information!